# View email online link not working properly

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

we're experiencing some odd issues with our standard %%view_email_url%% link.
In some cases, most of them triggered sends, the view online link works perfect, but if we check it again after some time (30-40 minutes), the online version is a different version of that email.

We're using ampscript to determine the Country, Language and Product variables we receive from our database, and based upon those values, we dynamically load the email. But as said above, sometimes the online version is an email in a different language, or different product.

Any ideas what might cause this? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

We have had this issue several times. This is usually related to the original data extension or a look up table.

Most of the time this is caused by the data extension being deleted or overwritten.

In your case, I believe that you are doing a triggered send, but using the same email address as a previous triggered send which used the same triggered data extension, thus the email address is in there more than once, so when the %%view_email_url%% page goes to find that recipient in the triggered data extension, the dynamic content may populate with the language/product from a previous send to the same recipient.